# MS Words doc includes two different tabs with two different lengths

Tags: microsoft-word

My MS word documents have two different types of tab in them which have two different lengths.  When you select paragraph marks, you would see a small arrow for the shorter tab and a longer arrow for the longer tab!  The funny thing is that when I want to have a half inch tab (standard), I have to hit the tab button twice (which shows as a short tab and immediately a long tab).  Any advice on how to get rid of the short tab?

Comment: Please post an example document.

Comment: Set tab stops and paragraph indents in Microsoft Word: [see this link] (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/set-tab-stops-and-paragraph-indents-in-microsoft-word-34361115-2b5a-9fcc-2d34-9d7c9e007b71)

Comment: What is the Style Name that is applied to the paragraphs where this is occurring? If you know how to open the Styles pane, locate the Style Name where this occurs and get a screen clip of the Style settings as you hover over it in the Styles Pane. Share that clip with us.